# fgetcsv not properly splitting comma's when reading from csv file

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I am trying to parse CSV data but struggling when the csv is comma delimited.

The function `fgetcsv()` is splitting commas on decimal numbers as well even though the fields are enclosed.
It works fine when manually copy a row from said csv file and use it as a variable to parse it with `str_getcsv()`.

I have no problems with other delimiters such as tab or semicolons only with commas.

For example:

```
$csv_string = '"OUT30045","stuk","16,70","1","1","5,00","0,0400","16,03","10,00","0,0750","15,45"';

print_r(str_getcsv($csv_string));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
[0] => OUT30045
[1] => stuk
[2] => 16,70
[3] => 1
[4] => 1
[5] => 5,00
[6] => 0,0400
[7] => 16,03
[8] => 10,00
[9] => 0,0750
[10] => 15,45
)
```

This is what I want and how it should be.

But when I try to read the same above information directly from the CSV file it splits the decimal values as well:

```
$csv_file = "PriceList_ART_comma.csv";
$file = new SplFileObject($csv_file, "r");

$fields = $file->fgetcsv();
print_r($fields);
```

Output:

```
Array(
[0] => "OUT30045"
[1] => "stuk"
[2] => "16
[3] => 70"
[4] => "1"
[5] => "1"
[6] => "5
[7] => 00"
[8] => "0
[9] => 0400"
[10] => "16
[11] => 03"
[12] => "10
[13] => 00"
[14] => "0
[15] => 0750"
[16] => "15
[17] => 45"
)
```

Since I have no control if users upload comma, tab or semicolon delimited files I have to get it to work for comma delimited files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sample of the CSV file:

```
"ItemCode","Unit","Price","UnitFactor","EntryMethod","Aantal1","Korting1","Nieuwe prijs1","Aantal2","Korting2","Nieuwe prijs2"
"IND300654","stuk","37,99","1","1",,,,,,
"IND300655","stuk","23,95","1","1",,,,,,
"IND300656","stuk","23,95","1","1",,,,,,
"IND300657","stuk","24,25","1","1",,,,,,
"OUT30045","stuk","16,70","1","1","5,00","0,0400","16,03","10,00","0,0750","15,45"
"OUT30055","stuk","39,20","1","1","5,00","0,0400","37,63",,,
"OUT30073","stuk","45,00","1","1","5,00","0,0400","43,20",,,
"OUT30074","stuk","45,00","1","1","5,00","0,0400","43,20",,,
```

Edit:

I think it might have something to do with the file itself.
I copied the contents of the CSV file and pasted in notepad and saved it as a .csv file.
When I use this new file, it all works fine...
Somehow the original CSV file cannot be read properly, perhaps because of some sort of encoding?

Edit Solved:

Found the cause of my problems. The original CSV file contained sort of NULL characters (chr(0)) after each character.
So dissecting for example "ItemCode" turn out to be something like "0I0t0e0m0c0o0d0e. After doing a str_replace(chr(0), "", $string) on each line, the str_getcsv() worked properly.

Comment: please post a small sample of the csv file

Comment: added the csv sample

Comment: the code works just fine using your sample, the only issue would be that the double quotes in your file aren't proper double quotes, char(34). Also the double quote is the default enclosure, so it should have worked by default.

Comment: I'll have a check on those double quotes. Thanks!

Comment: The encoding you experienced is utf-16 or ucs2 or something similar - Windows uses this as its wchar.